# Credit card debt past statute of limitations 1099C

Tags: income-tax, irs

I was issued a 1099c income for credit card debt that was relieved. The debt was made in 2018 in California, 3 year SOL.

That means the SOL expired in 2021 and it is now 2024, so it isn't legal debt. However the 1099 being issued means it is taxable income despite not being valid debt of any kind being written off.

Is it valid for the IRS to consider this write off taxable income, given that it isn't income or even valid debt to begin with? To make an analogy, if someone's estate took out a loan 100 years ago at 10% interest for $100, they would suddenly be hit out of nowhere with a 1099C for millions of dollars if that debt was written off.

Comment: Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post.

Comment: debt being uncollectable is not the same is the debt being invalid

Answer (score 2):

> the 1099 being issued means it is taxable income despite not being
> valid debt of any kind being written off.

This is the error in the question's logic.

The fact that something is reported on a 1099c doesn't mean that it is taxable income. It just alerts the IRS to the fact that there was a write off by the lender, which may or may not be taxable income.

Indeed, under the discharge of indebtedness tax rules, it isn't even necessarily taxable income if it was a valid debt. The relevant tax rules are found at [26 U.S.C. § 108](https://www.taxnotes.com/research/federal/usc26/108) and the related Treasury Regulations and Revenue Rulings.

The taxpayer to whom the 1099 was sent doesn't have to report it as income if it isn't income. It might be helpful for the taxapyer to file an explanatory note (there's an IRS form for that) to specifically call out and explain the reason that the 1099'd discharge of indebtedness income wasn't included as income on the taxpayer's tax return.